# How to use the `to_latex` method of pandas in Jupyter to obtain code that one can use directly in LaTeX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the multi-level index dataframe s

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
s
```

How may I convert it to a nice table in latex using python codes?

I tried

```
print s.to_latex()
```

but it failed and gave me this result

```
File "<ipython-input-45-d2f4611ecc13>", line 1
    print s.to_latex()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried

```
s.to_latex()
```

And the result was not organized at all

```
'\\begin{tabular}{llrrrr}\n\\toprule\n    &     &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 \\\\\n\\midrule\nbar & one & -0.008518 & -0.535653 & -0.603135 &  0.891277 \\\\\n    & two &  0.191005 & -1.470384 &  0.697245 &  1.054424 \\\\\nbaz & one &  0.414505 & -0.312967 &  0.703490 &  0.933851 \\\\\n    & two & -0.295505 & -0.923843 & -0.423998 &  0.160162 \\\\\nfoo & one & -1.339702 &  0.616059 &  0.519983 &  0.554584 \\\\\n    & two & -1.003784 &  0.674981 &  1.609906 &  0.274486 \\\\\nqux & one & -0.139274 & -0.783004 &  1.084794 &  2.202673 \\\\\n    & two & -0.730785 & -0.468041 &  0.762726 & -0.532599 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

Comment: In modern python, print is a function, so you need print() to see the printed output of the latex which will only show single \ characters. In Python strings the \ is represented by \\ because of special characters like \n.

Answer (score 7):

I was breaking my head with this the whole day.
I'd assume that you, like me, were working in a Jupyter environment and wanted to copy your results to a LaTex source.

In order to do that, you can surround the `s.to_latex` with a `print()` instruction and the output will be what you need for your LaTeX document.

In your example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
print(s.to_latex())
```

```
\begin{tabular}{llrrrr}
\toprule
    &     &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 \\
\midrule
bar & one &  0.371649 & -0.898747 &  1.996738 &  0.051273 \\
    & two & -0.409381 & -0.415512 & -1.975661 & -0.233850 \\
baz & one &  1.014193 & -0.789155 &  0.046733 &  0.142827 \\
    & two & -1.831074 & -1.743929 & -0.778236 &  1.408626 \\
foo & one &  0.040501 & -0.232053 &  0.979267 &  0.709616 \\
    & two & -0.407516 & -0.036641 & -0.286853 & -1.320493 \\
qux & one & -1.770540 &  0.490122 &  0.745257 & -0.921023 \\
    & two & -0.025855 & -1.567346 & -1.646400 & -2.411050 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is my workflow when I need to include a pandas dataframe/series in a latex document:

#### in python export your table to disk

```py
s.to_latex('./tables/the_table.tex')
```

#### in your main `.tex` file read in the table

```
\input{./tables/the_table.tex}
```

When you need to update the table in your latex document you just have to run your python code (e.g., notebook) followed by another latex compile to get the updated PDF.  No need for manually copy/pasting from a `print()` function in python.

Answer (score 0):

What were you expecting to get? this looks correct to me...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
s.to_latex()

u'\\begin{tabular}{llrrrr}\n\\toprule\n    &     &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 \\\\\n\\midrule\nbar & one & -0.792068 &  1.667280 &  0.996496 &  0.278456 \\\\\n    & two & -0.558638 &  0.329949 & -0.051455 &  0.586003 \\\\\nbaz & one &  0.400601 & -0.371393 &  1.041784 & -0.956686 \\\\\n    & two & -0.007604 & -1.332577 & -1.010781 & -0.448133 \\\\\nfoo & one &  0.567487 & -0.929883 &  0.022723 &  0.945251 \\\\\n    & two &  0.009925 &  0.556380 &  0.038697 &  0.067532 \\\\\nqux & one & -1.518476 & -1.706236 &  0.598467 &  1.439247 \\\\\n    & two &  0.644754 &  0.929502 &  0.327730 &  0.557668 \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\end{tabular}\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I was expecting to get a correct labeling as you may see in this label I may not just copy it an place it in my latex file. For example, it has \n and then \\toprule which should likely be \n then only one \ with \toprule